# Edit Settings Gear Icon

Tags: 2013

How can I edit the gear / settings list? I want to hide certain items from site owners.

[image: Gear Settings Icon]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by editing the master page thats being used currently.

How to identify the related items?

1.Open the .master page in some textpad/SP Designer.

2.Look for below tag. This is the holder for SITE ACTIONS

> <SharePoint:SiteActions

3.Look for the Menu item templates. These will clearly give you an idea on wht they will hold.

> <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate

4.There will be 2 attributes for each menu item called

> PermissionsString & PermissionMode.

Edit them as required.

Comment: Why has this post been voted down? Is it an invalid solution?

Comment: yes why is it voted down? its a valid answer. Admins, your intervention please. This is not to get any points, but people viewing this post may think that there is no way to achieve this

Comment: I am not the one downvote it. I want to add that I cannot find mentioned items in "seattle.html". I can only find them in "seattle.master". Shouldn't we avoid edit the .master file directly?

Comment: There is a seattle.html and also a seattle.master in "/_catalogs/masterpage/". You can see these in SharePoint designer when  you browse through: All files > _catalogs > masterpage. Please note that the HTML masterpage may require the Server Publishing site collection feature to be activated.