# How can I set the permissions to gear icon

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, permissions

I have 4 different type user groups I want to display gear icon for Site administrators and Site owners only.Where can I set the permissions to gear icon

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by editing the master page thats being used currently.

How to identify the related items?

1.Open the .master page in some textpad/SP Designer.

2.Look for below tag. This is the holder for SITE ACTIONS

```
<SharePoint:SiteActions
```

3.Look for the Menu item templates. These will clearly give you an idea on wht they will hold.

```
 <SharePoint:MenuItemTemplate
```

4.There will be 2 attributes for each menu item called

```
PermissionsString & PermissionMode.
```

Edit them as required.

[Reference](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/66628/edit-settings-gear-icon)

Comment: Do not edit the OOTB master pages, rather take a copy of it and modify the copy :)